# FeathersJS: How to move from mongodb to mongoose services?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm developing an app using FeathersJS, and I started the app using feathers-mongodb adapter. Now I'd like to move everything to mongoose because I think it will be easier to set the constraints I'm facing (compound indexes, schema validation, etc...). Is there any "automagic" way or at least a "some kind of easy" way to convert all my services from mongodb to mongoose?

Thank you!

Comment: I think there is no easy way to do this but still a lot easier compare to moving from sql to mongoose. In this case, you need to make sure that your mongoose schema will replicate the ones in your mongodb ( indexes, collection, document type, etc).

Comment: Hello Jalil. Thank you for your answer, but I was referring to FeathersJS itself and not to any kind of "generic" way to change from one to the other. FeathersJS has a CLI that automatically generates the services for the specified adapter, and as it automatically generates the code for every service, I wanted to know if there was any kind of FeathersJS way to move from mongodb adapter FeathersJS service to mongoose adapter FeathersJS service. But anyway, thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend migrating your project using the newer `feathers-plus cli`, and then you can switch between mongo/mongoose and any other adapter to your hearts content!

https://generator.feathers-plus.com/get-started/#generate-service

All you need to do is initially generate your service, and then you can modify the `service/service.schema.js` file, regenerate the service (or all of them, with `feathers generate all`, and then you will have updated mongo/mongoose models to work with - (`service.mongo.js` and `service.mongoose.js` respectively)

Edit: I should add that there's no `automagic` way to do this with the existing CLI - but the `feathers-plus` CLI will let you achieve what you're looking for.